# EmberJS accessing an association's data on create

Tags: ember.js

I have 2 models: Task and Project, with a project having multiple tasks. But how can I create a new task for a specific project?

I have this route:
`@resource('projects', ->
    @route('show', { path: '/:project_id' })`

And in the projects/show-template I'm calling `{{render "tasks" model.tasks}}` to show all tasks belonging to a project + an input-helper to add a new Task. The problem is that I have no idea how to get to the project's id in the createTask-action (which resides inside the TasksController).

I can't access the params and I don't want to use a regex on the window.location to get to the id.

(EmberJS 1.10.0)

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like

```
this.store.createRecord('task', {project: this.modelFor('projects/show')});
```

You get the project from the `projects/show` route and set the `task`'s `project` property to the object.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. `this` doesn't know about modelFor.

Comment: modelFor is a method on Route (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor), so this should work on a route. The general idea is to set project to the correct **object**. - Where do you try to get this working, could you post the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving the input helper to a Ember.Component, which I then added to the projects/show-template and passed the project to: `{{add-task project=model}}`. I also moved the createTask()-action from the TasksController to the new component.